# Concrete Mathematics: What is polynomial argument

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

In the book *Concrete Mathematics: A foundation for Computer Science* of the chapter *Binomial Coefficients*, It gives an identity

$$
(r - k) {r \choose k} = r {r - 1 \choose k}
$$

for positive integers r.

Then it claims that it can be proved for real r, because both sides of polynomials in $r$ of degree $k + 1$, by giving the following argument

> A nonzero polynomial of degree $d$ or less can have at most $d$ distinct zeros; therefore the difference of two such polynomials, which also has degree d or less, cannot be zero at more than d points unless it is identically zero. In other words if two polynomials of degree d or less agree at more than d points, they must agree everywhere. We have shown that $(r - k) {r \choose k} = r {r - 1 \choose k}$ whenever $r$ is positive integer; so these two polynomials agree at infinitely many points, and they must be identically equal.

I don't understand the argument at all.

1. How a polynomial of degree $d$ or less can have at most $d$ distinct zeros.
2. How they must agree everywhere if they agree at more than $d$ points.

Is there an article about *polynomial argument*. I have read about polynomial before, but I can't get my head around this argument! Maybe I have forgot some properties.

Comment: Lookup the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem). If $P(r)$ of degree $d \ge 1$ has a root $a$ then $P(r)=(r-a)Q(r)$ where $Q(r)$ has degree $d-1$. It follows by induction that $P(r)$ can have at most $d$ roots.

Comment: “ How a polynomial of degree 
d
 or less can have at most 
d
distinct zeros?” [This is the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: @insipidintegrator Using the fundamental theorem for this is overkill.

Comment: I mean, the OP literally asked how [insert statement of FTA] is true. What, according to you, would be a better response? I’m just clarifying one of OP’s questions, not solving the whole problem

Comment: @insipidintegrator The fundamental theorem says that any polynomial has at least one zero, not what is stated by OP.

Comment: Okay, but can’t we interpret “total number of real and complex roots ( including multiplicity) is n” as “total number of distinct real roots is $\leq$ n”? Probably overkill, but anyway.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I think that's usually seen as an easy corollary of the fundamental theorem after incorporating the argument given by dxiv.

Comment: @insipidintegrator The fact that a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ distinct roots is something much easier to prove than the fundamental theorem of algebra. This question does not need the fundamental theorem of algebra. The fundamental theorem of algebra asserts the *existence* of a root to a polynomial with real or complex coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

The argument for (1) is given by dxiv. More precisely, a *nonzero* polynomial of degree $d$ or less can have at most $d$ zeros. It follows that a polynomial of degree $d$ or less with more than $d$ zeros must be the zero polynomial.

Suppose that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have degree less than or equal to $d$ and agree at more than $d$ points. Then $p(x)-q(x)$ has degree less than or equal to $d$ but is zero at more than $d$ points. We must have $p(x)-q(x)=0,$ so $p(x)=q(x).$

Comment: Yes, I agree this is better than Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.+1

Comment: Why is it saying $d$ or less ?

Comment: @Abhisek  Which one? Your text claims that if two polynomials of degree $d$ or less agree at more than $d$ points then they must agree everywhere. This is a proof of that claim.

Comment: @subrosar How a polynomial of degree $d-1$ can have at most d distinct zeros ? Shouldn't it be polynomial of degree $d$ can have at most $d$ distinct zeros and *not $d$ or less*.

Comment: @Abhisek "d or less" and "at most d" actually mean the same thing, $\leq d$.